# "When needed": Passive voice or adjective?

Tags: passive-voice

I've just read this sentence:

> ...As long as they have their own independent lives and help out only **when needed**, mothers-in-law can play a very useful role in any family...

My question is about "when needed". Is it correct? It shouldn't be "when *is* needed"?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, short for *when they are needed*; see [ellipsis (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Answer (score 1):

The adjective is *necessary* which in the context you provided could fit as *when deemed necessary*. So, *needed* is the past participle of the verb *need* forming a passive clause which in its expanded version should be "when they are needed", "they" referring to "mothers-in-law" which occurs in the main clause, i.e. "mothers-in-law...in any family".

Comment: Why can't _needed_ be considered an adjective here? **needed**
... adjective: necessary, wanted, required, lacked, lacking, called for, desired [Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/needed).

Comment: It can be. Either way, "when needed" or "when they are needed" forms an adverbial phrase. It seems it doesn't really matter whether you parse it as adjective or passive.