# Passive or Adjective 'respected'

Tags: adjectives, past-tense, passive-voice, participles

Is the following sentence passive or is 'respected' used an adjective?:

> He is respected.

And how would one know the difference?

Comment: An isolated three-word sentence is not a valid example. Please give some context.

Comment: What difference does it make? It's still exactly the same word with exactly the same meaning, regardless of how you categorise it. You might as well ask the same question about ***This herb is dried***.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584276/is-entitled-a-passive-voice-verb-or-adjective-in-everyone-is-entitled-to-resp/584280#584280

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "entitled" a passive voice verb or adjective in "everyone is entitled to respect"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584276/is-entitled-a-passive-voice-verb-or-adjective-in-everyone-is-entitled-to-resp)

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions: [owned](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598585/the-buildings-are-owned-by-him-is-this-a-verbal-stative-passive-or-an-adjecti), [needed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244351/when-needed-passive-voice-or-adjective), [advised](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547658/imperative-be-passive-please-be-advised), [attached](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/490634/is-the-word-attached-in-the-sentence-please-find-attached-the-file-passiv)...